# JOptionPane inputDialog method doesn`t show horizontal scroll bar instead stretch the width of dialog with the largest data in the list

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @author hxd1
 *
 */
public class demoDialog
{
  public static final String[] pizzas = { "Cheeseassssssssssss123333331231231232111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss232222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222224", "Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Veggie","Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Veggie","Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Veggie","Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Veggie","Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Veggie","Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Veggie","Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Veggie","Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Veggie" };

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What's your name?","Title",     JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, pizzas, null);
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Above code upon execution shows dialog with no horizontal scroll instead frame stretching w.r.t largest data.

Is there anything we could do to solve this?

Comment: Why should it?  `JOptionPane` doesn't have a `JScrollPane` attached to it.  Ever considered using a `JComboBox` instead?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anything we could do to solve this

- Use a `JComboBox` as the message parameter.  The problem with this is, `JComboBox` will size to it's widest element...
- Use a `JList` configured to a single selection.  The problem with this is, it's a little confusing from a selection point of view
- Use a `JTable` with a `JRadioButton` in one column.  Not much better then the `JList`, but it provides a slightly better visual cue

[image: List of pizzas]

```
JList list = new JList(pizzas) {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
        dim.width = 25;
        return dim;
    }
};
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

switch (JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list), "Pizza", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, 0)) {
    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
        // Get the selected index/item
        break;
}
```

Don't forget, you could wrap the `JList` in a `JPanel` and other components, like a `JLabel` as prompt